# Is there any way to use re-resizable in the MUI material popover?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, resize, popover, resizable

I am trying to use the [re-resizable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/re-resizable) resizable to change the size of the [popover](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/) but it is not working, is it impossible? and if so is there another way to resize the popover?

```
return (
<Resizable>
  <Popover
    open={!isStoredTabsNull()}
    onClose={handleClose}
    anchorEl={anchorEl}>
      <Paper
        style={{
          backgroundColor: DefaultStyle.backgroundColor,
          overflow: 'auto'}}>
            { storedTabs?.map((tabsGroup) => (
              <StoredTabsItem
                key={tabsGroup.id}
                storedTabsGroup={tabsGroup}
                projectFolder={projectFolder}
                openFiles={openFiles}
                overwriteState={overwriteState}
             tabs={tabs}
         />
     ))}
   </Paper>
 </Popover>
</Resizable>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

In a nutshell, wrap your `Popover` content (children) in `<Resizable>`, and not the `Popover` itself, to make it re-size.

### Explanation

Yes, it is possible to resize an [MUI Popover](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/) with [re-resizable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/re-resizable). Like the underlying [`Modal` component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-modal/), `Popover`'s sizing is driven, by default, by its content. Adding a child[ren] wrapped in `Resizable` will give you the ability to resize the `Popover`.  For example:

```
<Popover
  open={!isStoredTabsNull()}
  onClose={handleClose}
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  anchorOrigin={{
    vertical: "bottom",
    horizontal: "left"
  }}
>
  <Paper
    style={{
      backgroundColor: DefaultStyle.backgroundColor,
      overflow: "auto"
    }}
  >
    <Resizable>
      {storedTabs?.map((tabsGroup) => (
        <StoredTabsItem
          key={tabsGroup.id}
          storedTabsGroup={tabsGroup}
          projectFolder={projectFolder}
          openFiles={openFiles}
          overwriteState={overwriteState}
          tabs={tabs}
        />
      ))}
    </Resizable>
  </Paper>
</Popover>
```

*(In this example using your code, I added `Resizable` inside of `Paper` because `Paper` also gets its height from its content, unless otherwise defined.)*

Which will result in:
[image: example of resized popover]

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-popover-with-re-resizeable-forked-t96dko?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found a different way. If anyone else is looking for a simpler answer that doesn't require to install another library you can use the CSS property [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) (both meaning: "The element displays a mechanism for allowing the user to resize it, which may be resized both horizontally and vertically."(Source:developer.mozilla.org)

```
return (
  <Popover
    open={!isStoredTabsNull()}
    onClose={handleClose}
    anchorEl={anchorEl}>
      <Paper
        style={{
          backgroundColor: DefaultStyle.backgroundColor,
          overflow: 'auto',
           resize: "both",
        }}>
            { storedTabs?.map((tabsGroup) => (
              <StoredTabsItem
                key={tabsGroup.id}
                storedTabsGroup={tabsGroup}
                projectFolder={projectFolder}
                openFiles={openFiles}
                overwriteState={overwriteState}
             tabs={tabs}
         />
     ))}
   </Paper>
 </Popover>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "PaperProps" to give height and width like this. No need to use Resizeable.

```
<Popover
  open={!isStoredTabsNull()}
  onClose={handleClose}
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  PaperProps={{
    style: { width: 400, height: 400 },
  }}
>
  <Paper
    style={{
      backgroundColor: DefaultStyle.backgroundColor,
      overflow: "auto",
    }}
  >
    {storedTabs?.map((tabsGroup) => (
      <StoredTabsItem
        key={tabsGroup.id}
        storedTabsGroup={tabsGroup}
        projectFolder={projectFolder}
        openFiles={openFiles}
        overwriteState={overwriteState}
        tabs={tabs}
      />
    ))}
  </Paper>
</Popover>;
```

Comment: But isn't it possible to change the size dynamically (with the mouse)?

Comment: Actually you can do it but it will work poorly. You can put a new component between <Resizable> and <Popover> and if your library allows you can change the size of that new component, also you need to hold the data of new component's width and height and than set the that width height to PaperProps that is inside of the popover. If you use state with that it will probably work but not sure if it is going to look good.